# ANTLR4 - How to change source code and get it back?

Tags: antlr4

I'd like to rewrite some of the code.

Then, I'd like to get the rewritten code back.

First, I'd like to replace string literals:

```
local var = "%%var%%"
// to
local var = "SOMETHING"
```

Second, I'd like to erase the function name and brackets:

```
function sayHello (a)
  local var = "%%var%%"
  print("Hello")
end
//to
function (a)
  local var = "%%var%%"
  print("Hello")
end
```

What's the suggested way to do so?

My target's JavaScript (specifically `antlr4ts`), however an answer in any language is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TokenStreamRewriter`

```
const stream = CharStreams.fromString(code);
const lexer = new LuaLexer(stream);
const commonTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
const rewriter = new TokenStreamRewriter(commonTokenStream);

const parser = new LuaParser(commonTokenStream);

const tree = parser.chunk();

class MyVisitor extends AbstractParseTreeVisitor<any>
  implements LuaVisitor<any> {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  visitString(ctx: StringContext) {
    rewriter.replace(ctx.start.tokenIndex, ctx.stop?.tokenIndex!, "SOME REPLACEMENT");
  }
}

console.log("rewriter", rewriter.getText());
```